# If condition is not behaving like it should be

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm fairly new to game  programming, and made a simple platformer game with JS.

```js
(function() {
    var requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame;
    window.requestAnimationFrame = requestAnimationFrame;
})();

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    player = {
     x: 0,
     y: canvas.height - 25,
     velX: 0,
     velY: 0,
     speed: 5,
     width: 25,
     height: 25,
     friction: 0.9,
     gravity: 0.2,
     jumping: false
    },
    keys = [];
document.body.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    keys[e.keyCode] = true;
});
 
document.body.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
    keys[e.keyCode] = false;
});
function rect(x, y, width, height, color) {
 ctx.fillStyle = color;
 ctx.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
 ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
}
function update() {
 if (keys[87]) {
  if (!player.jumping) {
   player.jumping = true;
   player.velY = -player.speed * 2;
  }
    }
    if (keys[68]) {
        if (player.velX < player.speed) {                         
            player.velX++;                  
        }          
    }          
    if (keys[65]) {                                  
        if (player.velX > -player.speed) {
            player.velX--;
        }
 }
 if (player.x >= canvas.width - player.width) {
     player.x = canvas.width - player.width;
 } else if (player.x <= 0) {
     player.x = 0;
 }
 if (player.y >= canvas.height - player.height) {
     player.y = canvas.height - player.height;
      player.jumping = false;
 }
 player.x += player.velX;
 player.y += player.velY;
 player.velX *= player.friction;
 player.velY += player.gravity;
 ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
 rect(player.x, player.y, player.width, player.height, 'black');
 requestAnimationFrame(update);
}
requestAnimationFrame(update);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Platformy stuff</title>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="canvas" style="border:1px solid #000" width=1339 height=619></canvas>
<script src='game.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the problem. I made this condition:

```
if (player.y >= canvas.height - player.height) {
        player.y -= canvas.height - player.height;
        player.jumping = false;
    }
```

So as you can see, this was suppose to prevent the player from falling out of the canvas. So If the player got push out by the gravity `player.y += gravity`, the condition would set it back to the bottom of the canvas. However, It doesn't really work out. I would be glad if someone could help me with this, thanks.

Comment: your indentation looks a bit misleading.

Comment: English isn't my native language, sorry if it was confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cant seem to edit or do not see an edit link/button so here is another answer:

To fix this just put your check code for the payer below canvas above your check for the keypress of key 87 and set velocity to 0.

In other words put the test for the "player is below canvas" as first check in update function. This will work and is tested. Although you may want to gradually nudge the player back up instead of abruptly moving to the edge. And set the velocity to 0. Now to nudge him you could gradually set to 0 based on how far down the payer is. Ill leave that to you.

```
function update() {
    if (player.y >= canvas.height - player.height) {
        player.jumping = false;
        player.y = canvas.height - player.height;
        player.velY = 0;
    }

    if (keys[87]) {...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you subtracting the canvas height combined with the player height and you want it to be set to it instead to keep it at the edge. Simply remove the - from -=.

player.y = canvas.height - player.height;

Comment: The `-` was a typo. It wasn't intended to be there, sorry :( It doesn't work after I removed it also.